# ViewPager on Xamarin.Android hugging all the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, viewpagerindicator

I cannot find out why the viewpagerindicator does not shows up on the screen when is put below the viewpager on the activity layout.

On the layout file of the activity I have a ViewPager follow by a ViewPagerIndicator. The ViewPagerIndicator does not appear. If a change the order of the elements, first the viewpagerindicator and then viewpager it works.

The activity layout has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/menuPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <dk.ostebaronen.droid.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:fillColor="#FF888888"
        app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
        app:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout file of the fragment that the viewpager has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMenuName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMenuDescription"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMenuPrice"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff07df1c"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The target version I’m using is API Level 15.

Why does the ViewPagerIndicator does not appear when is below the viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the activity layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/menuPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <dk.ostebaronen.droid.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:fillColor="#FF888888"
        app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
        app:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The viewpager has 0dp height and a weight of 1.